How to plot a Column of 3 Pie Charts
this is the question of the course
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/online-courses/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/04-displaying-lists.html

Make a column of pie charts with 1,2 and 3 identical segments

and this is the answer I try

Column[PieChart[{1}],PieChart[{1,1}] PieChart[{1,1,1}]]

Apparently, the Wolfram check button says it's wrong.
If you have any ideas how to fix this.
I am very thankful for any suggestions you might want to provide.

You must surround the interior of Column with curly braces: Column[{PieChart[{1}], PieChart[{1, 1}], PieChart[{1, 1, 1}]}]

Thank you, because your answer solves my question.
